# TranslateLoader with Standalone Component [Angular16]

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I have an Angular 16 standalone application, and i'm having issues with the Translate imports.

My current code looks like this:

main.ts

```
*Some non relevant imports*
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

const combinedConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        defaultLanguage: 'en',
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      })
    ),
    // Otras configuraciones de providers si es necesario
  ],
  ...appConfig, // Expansión de appConfig después de la configuración específica de TranslateModule
};


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, combinedConfig).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

inventario.component.ts

```
*non relevant imports*

import { TranslateStore, TranslateService,TranslateModule,TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'inventario',
    templateUrl: 'inventario.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['inventario.component.scss'],
    host: { 'class': 'u-main-container' },
    standalone: true,
    imports:[CommonModule, StepperNuevaCaptacionComponent, ClarityModule, TranslateModule],
    providers: [CatalogoAprovechamientosService, NotificationService, TranslateService, TranslateStore],
})
```

The error i'm currently experiencing is:

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[InventarioComponent])[TranslateLoader -> TranslateLoader -> TranslateLoader -> TranslateLoader -> TranslateLoader]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateLoader!

I suposedly already imported the TranslateLoader interface into my code, but seems like something its not working properly and i can't tell what it is, i've been stucked with this for serveral weeks already.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Already tried the next links:

[Medium](https://medium.com/@grzeda/how-to-use-ngrx-translate-with-angular-standalone-api-bc4d93d7158)

[GitHub](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1398)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the providers array is getting overridden by `appConfig` could you try this small change?

> if the appConfig has its own providers array, then the previous definition of providers will get overridden rather than merged!

```
const combinedConfig = {
    ...appConfig, // Expansión de appConfig después de la configuración específica de TranslateModule
    providers: [
      provideHttpClient(),
      importProvidersFrom(
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          defaultLanguage: 'en',
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient],
          },
        })
      ),
      ...(appConfig.providers && appConfig.providers.length ? appConfig.providers: [])
      // Otras configuraciones de providers si es necesario
    ],
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Naren! Your answser actually work!, i was totally lost i would never have been able to do this without your help, Angular imports are a pain for me sometimes. I will set you answer as the accepted one. Now i will try to fix why the i18n file is giving a 404 :)

Comment: Hi @NaremMurali Translate Module is working correctly as expected. But i'm having a issue with it when i load a Angular Steper that its inside a different component.

When this stepper its opened after presing a button, the translate modules are no executed, so tags still appear as "global.obligatorio" rather than the straight string. Any insight of what could be causing this? thank you very much in advance and my most sincere greetings.

Comment: @LuisBauer please create a new question and a stackblitz with the issue reproduced